# eth_getLogs is returning empty array on Astar

Tags: frontier, evm, astar

With recent updates in frontier eth_getLogs is returning empty array

```
curl -X POST --data '{"id": 1, "jsonrpc":"2.0","method": "eth_getLogs","params": [{"address":"0x841ce48f9446c8e281d3f1444cb859b4a6d0738c", "topics":[], "fromBlock": "0x14D7F5", "toBlock": "0x14D7F7"}]}' https://rpc.astar.network:8545 (https://rpc.astar.network:8545/) -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

While the logs are there in block explorer https://blockscout.com/astar/tx/0xb92e1c21bbeb31f6854456a1529faa3dcea79de446ecfdc92118aca3aed9b40f/logs

Answer (score 1):

When I run:

```
$ curl -X POST --data '{"id": 1, "jsonrpc":"2.0","method": "eth_getLogs","params": [{"address":"0x841ce48f9446c8e281d3f1444cb859b4a6d0738c", "topics":[], "fromBlock": "0x14D7F5", "toBlock": "0x14D7F7"}]}' https://rpc.astar.network:8545 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I get the following result:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"address":"0x841ce48f9446c8e281d3f1444cb859b4a6d0738c","blockHash":"0x7afa51ec6ef05e41cd4cbe8879f4ecc6a765f7892e547f6341b4b1392381ea96","blockNumber":"0x14d7f6","data":"0x5cd11dbc09c77658576c5c498fb2f4c69d23fdba95df1c42bc494a9f3afc0bab00000000000000000000000027ee985d1e446ec71c277c89cd877ec4eeaa236c00000000000000000000000027ee985d1e446ec71c277c89cd877ec4eeaa236c0000000000000000000000006a2d262d56735dba19dd70682b39f6be9a931d980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005ebb0b60000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038e446e1edeb0820082749ec71be560d667c964744fa39cf179ee1f6b8b6826cb8","logIndex":"0x10","removed":false,"topics":["0x79fa08de5149d912dce8e5e8da7a7c17ccdf23dd5d3bfe196802e6eb86347c7c"],"transactionHash":"0xb92e1c21bbeb31f6854456a1529faa3dcea79de446ecfdc92118aca3aed9b40f","transactionIndex":"0x6","transactionLogIndex":"0x1"}],"id":1}
```

I do not see an empty array.

Comment: same result ^^^

Comment: This is because we reverted evm node before the PR. Bug is being discussed on frontier repo https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/issues/761